# App Engine default credentials restore after deletion (+ 30 days)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

A long time ago someone deleted the Google App Engine default credential (service account) and since it's passed much more than 30 days, we are not able to deploy apps using App Engine anymore. I already read a lot of things and technical workarounds within stack over flow community but could not find anything that resolved this issue.

Is there anything that works for that? Recover? Replacing the service account for another new one? Force the app to use another service account instead of the default?

Comment: Have you tried using a different service account when deploying https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/user-managed-service-accounts? If so do you get any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a different service account when deploying. [See](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/user-managed-service-accounts).